# Difference between Side loading Feature and Developer Feature in case of O365

Tags: sharepoint-online

Please let me to know the  pros and Cons of enabling Side loading Feature and Developer Feature in case of Office 365.

What makes them different?

Answer (score 4):

**SiteLoading**

> App sideloading, from a SharePoint context, is the ability to install
>   a SharePoint app directly into a site to explicitly bypass the regular
>   governance controls of SharePoint. The main reason for blocking
>   sideloading by default on **non-developer sites is the risk that faulty
>   apps pose to their host web/host site collection**. Apps have the
>   potential to destroy data and make sites or, given enough permissions,
>   can even make site collections unusable. Therefore, **apps should only
>   be sideloaded in dev/test environments and in production only when
>   deploying from the AppCatalog does not meet your needs.** It is NOT
>   recommended to sideload SharePoint Hosted-Applications, because of the
>   risk of data loss.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/frank_marasco/archive/2014/07/26/side-loading.aspx

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Administrators can deploy apps to their tenancy basically in two different ways.
Deploy from the app catalog (“app stapling”) or via Sideloading.

**Centrally Deployed Apps** Vs **Sideloading** comparison

**App Stapling** (Deploy from the app catalog)

1. Custom actions and app parts are not supported
2. App Install, Uninstall and upgrade event receivers cannot be handled
3. Site Collection Administrators cannot uninstall the application
4. Applied to new and existing site collections
5. There is metadata about the app and updates are applied

**Sideloading** (Installing Provider hosted applications programmactically)

1. Custom actions and app parts are supported
2. App Install, Uninstall and upgrade event receivers do fire and can be handled
3. Site Collection Administrators can uninstall the application
4. Custom code must be used to install the application
5. Tenant Administrators must enable the sideloading feature prior to install the application and should be disabled after the application is installed
6. There is no metadata about the app and updates have to be managed manually

Official Office Dev PnP (Patterns and Practices) post on the same: http://dev.office.com/patterns-and-practices-detail/1891